# how to remove specific character in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have the variable that get data from numpy for example

```
dataInput = pd.io.parsers.read_csv(url, sep=',')
dataList['date'] = np.array(dataInput['Date'])
```

and my dataList['date'] format is '06/14/2016' 
but i have some function that will use the format 06142016

I try to use some method but it have an error :

```
>>> date = dataList['date'][0]
>>> print (date)
>>> '06/14/2016'
>>> newDate = date.replace("/", "")
>>> AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

and also using strip

```
>>> newDate = date.strip( "/" )
>>> AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

so, it have any way to reformat my date.

```
>>> date = dataList['date'][0]
>>> print (date)
>>> '06/14/2016'
>>> newDate = SOME FUNCTION ()
>>> print (newDate)
>>> 06142016
```

Thank you.

I don't know how to create a best title for this problem so you can comment me and i will edit it :) sorry for unclear question

Comment: assign variable a = dataList['date'] and then replace the not required character using a.replace('/','')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to convert it to a string first and then call replace

```
my_string_date = str(date).replace('/', '')
```

Comment: Thank you @upZone
but i still have problem with " ' " i can't remove it by use .replace(" ' ", "")

Comment: "i can't remove it by use .replace(" ' ", "")" Did you want to convert to `int`? The variable you have is string. For escape characters you will need to use `.replace('\'','')`